# Form and Grid inside a Tab in EXT-JS app

Tags: forms, extjs, tabs, grid

I am trying to display a search-form and grid in EXT-JS application. I am trying this:

```
items: [
                {
                    title: 'myTab',
                    xtype: 'myform',
                    xtype:'mygrid',
                    flex:1
                }
       ]
```

My Problem: When I comment out

```
xtype: 'mygrid'
```

I can see the search form. When I uncomment the line, grid overlaps the form. how can I solve this problem?

UPDATE: I see that I need to use vbox layout. I a m trying it in various ways, but unable to figure out where it should be placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is how I added layout to the code:

```
items: Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            activeTab: 0,
            layout : {            // This is how to save the form from being overlapped by the                      
                                  //grid panel.

                    type: 'vbox',

                    align: 'fit'

                },

            items: [
                {

                    title: 'Single-Activity Resource',
                    items : [

                                {

                                    xtype:'myform'

                                },

                                {

                                    xtype:'mygrid',

                                    flex: 1

                                }

                            ]
                } ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing arrays (i.e. `[...]`), and objects (i.e. `{...}`).

The `items` option in Ext containers must be an **array of objects**. Objects in there can be raw configuration object or instantiated components.

So the syntax you must use looks like the following:

```
items: [
    {
        title: 'myTab',
        xtype: 'myform'
    },{
        title: "Grid Tab",
        xtype:'mygrid'
    }
]
```

See, this is similar to an array of integers like `[1,2,3]` except that elements are objects `{...}` instead of numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your time friend. I will upvote your answer because it explains how to use arrays correctly. But this is not what I was looking for. Request you to see my own answer, which I figured out for the "actual" problem which I was facing. My grid panel was overlapping the form panel. And it works fine!!! :) Thanks once again.